# Customization of tableView delete option

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

Currently, I am using the following process:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

to delete a row in a tableView.

I am using the swipe functionality to get the red delete button. But I feel this is still a bit painful process for the user. Is there a way in which i can delete the row without having the swipe action? Can I customize the entire process of deleting a row using tableView delegate methods? Is it possible to customize the red delete button to something else so that it gives a different look and feel to the user?

Comment: See SO posts like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615469/custom-delete-button-on-editing-in-uitableview-cell, to help you decide if it's the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to delete or insert multiple cells at a time by using UITableView's `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`
 [Check my post on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560602/add-delete-uitableviewcell-with-animation/5564842#comment-6347629)

Perhaps you could design your code such that when your are editing the table, the user taps each cell, and then presses a button to commit the changes to all the relevent at once?