# Custom edit view in UITableViewCell while swipe left. Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swipe

How to make a custom edit view in iOS7 UITableView with Objective C like the Evernote or the Apple Reminders app while swipe left. 
I have tried to set an custom editingAccessoryView, but this didn't work.

Evernote edit view:

[image]
Reminders edit view:

[image]

My current code is

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSLog(@"delete");
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve the problem with: (UITableViewController.h)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //make cell

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    //add Buttons to view

    cell.editingAccessoryView = view;

    return cell;
}
```

And the same with: (UITableViewCell)

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state;
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (UIView*)editingAccessoryView;
```

Comment: can we make the height  fix for the side swipe buttons? eg: my cell is 150 and i want button to be show only 50.0f is it possible?

Answer (score 100):

Just copy paste the code below!

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    UITableViewRowAction *editAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Clona" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
       //insert your editAction here
    }];
    editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    
    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Delete"  handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
       //insert your deleteAction here
    }];
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return @[deleteAction,editAction];
}
```

Comment: To get these to show up in my case, I also needed to implement the table view's dataSource method - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;  
Even an empty implementation of this method was sufficient to get the buttons to show up.

Comment: I've converted this to Swift and posted it as a new answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33748345/470879

Comment: @sohil which image? you are having an imageview in your cell?
So you are getting a handler in that method which i have written which will be called when you tap on any of the buttons

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question. The submitter specifically asked how to set icons for the swipe actions instead of text.

Comment: @mattsson, the question is vague in that regard, and doesn't mention icons at all. It mentions Evernote and Apple Reminders as examples. The Apple Reminders app uses a standard implementation like this answer.

Comment: @MattyG You're completely right, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 45):

**Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
        //TODO: edit the row at indexPath here
    }
    editAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
        //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return [editAction,deleteAction]
}
```

**Swift 2.1**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (rowAction:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        //TODO: edit the row at indexPath here
    }
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete") { (rowAction:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
    }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [editAction,deleteAction]
}
```

Note: for iOS 8 onwards

Comment: swift 3 - Swipe doesn't seem to work !! No options are shown !!

Comment: @Maven, have you implemented canEditRowAtIndexPath to return true?

Comment: I've noticed you also need to at least write     `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }` or     `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called

Comment: how to add images instead of text?

Comment: Isn't there a memory leak when you create a closure which references to `self`?

Comment: It is now working for section headers, do you  why?

Comment: can we make the height  fix for the side swipe buttons? eg: my cell is 150 and i want button to be show only 50.0f is it possible?

Comment: Also setting the background color is not necessary. For destructive actions use the .destructive style, for others it can be .normal, in this case some system defaults will be used. In fact the destructive one is not exactly pure .red, it's something else.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `UITableViewRowAction`'s `backgroundColor` to set custom image or view. The trick is using `UIColor(patternImage:)`.

Basically the width of `UITableViewRowAction` area is decided by its title, so you can find a exact length of title(or whitespace) and set the exact size of image with `patternImage`.

To implement this, I made a `UIView`'s extension method.

```
func image() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return UIImage()
    }
    layer.render(in: context)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

and to make a string with whitespace and exact length,

```
fileprivate func whitespaceString(font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15), width: CGFloat) -> String {
    let kPadding: CGFloat = 20
    let mutable = NSMutableString(string: "")
    let attribute = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
    while mutable.size(attributes: attribute).width < width - (2 * kPadding) {
        mutable.append(" ")
    }
    return mutable as String
}
```

and now, you can create `UITableViewRowAction`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let whitespace = whitespaceString(width: kCellActionWidth)
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .`default`, title: whitespace) { (action, indexPath) in
        // do whatever you want
    }

    // create a color from patter image and set the color as a background color of action
    let kActionImageSize: CGFloat = 34
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: kCellActionWidth, height: kCellHeight))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (kCellActionWidth - kActionImageSize) / 2,
                                              y: (kCellHeight - kActionImageSize) / 2,
                                              width: 34,
                                              height: 34))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "x")
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    let image = view.image()

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

The result will look like this.

[image]

Another way to do this is to import custom font which has the image you want to use as a font and use `UIButton.appearance`. However this will affect other buttons unless you manually set other button's font.

**From iOS 11, it will show this message `[TableView] Setting a pattern color as backgroundColor of UITableViewRowAction is no longer supported.`. Currently it is still working, but it wouldn't work in the future update.**

==========================================

## For iOS 11+, you can use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
  let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
    // Perform your action here
      completion(true)
  }

  let muteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Mute") { (action, view, completion) in
    // Perform your action here
    completion(true)
  }

  deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "icon.png")
  deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, muteAction])
}
```

Comment: Could you clarrify the func image() -> UIImage {}  I have errors ebcause there is no varaible bounds.size in its first line.  likewise in the 5th line hthere is no layer variable... Since the function does not take in any variables.  Thank you

Comment: That is an 'UIView''s extension. So bounds will be the instance's bounds.

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME, exactly what  I was looking for.  Very creative implementation, love it! Thank you

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't be using init directly: `deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: image)` should be `deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)`. Awesome answer though

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution was exactly what I was looking for but unfortunately, it will only work for very small images because the "whitespace" padding no longer increases the size past the minimum width. I tried a non-breaking space \u{00a0} but it still is always the minimum size. I wonder if there's another unicode character that's blank that actually takes up space?

Answer (score 13):

You Can try this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let backView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80))
    backView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.933103919, green: 0.08461549133, blue: 0.0839477703, alpha: 1)

    let myImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: backView.frame.size.height/2-14, width: 16, height: 16))
    myImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rubbish-bin")
    backView.addSubview(myImage)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: myImage.frame.origin.y+14, width: 80, height: 25))
    label.text = "Remove"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 14)
    backView.addSubview(label)

    let imgSize: CGSize = tableView.frame.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    backView.layer.render(in: context!)
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "           ") { (action, indexPath) in
        print("Delete")
    }

    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage)

    return [delete, share]
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Refer this link : https://github.com/TeehanLax/UITableViewCell-Swipe-for-Options

And customize your uitableviewcell with multiple button.

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) + kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

[self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
self.scrollView = scrollView;

UIView *scrollViewButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - kCatchWidth, 0, kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
self.scrollViewButtonView = scrollViewButtonView;
[self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewButtonView];

// Set up our two buttons
UIButton *moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f];
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[moreButton setTitle:@"More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[moreButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:moreButton];

UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
shareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
shareButton.frame = CGRectMake(kCatchWidth / 3.0f, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[shareButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:shareButton];

UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188f alpha:1.0f];
deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(kCatchWidth / 3.0f+kCatchWidth / 3.0f, 0, kCatchWidth / 3.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
[deleteButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:deleteButton];

UIView *scrollViewContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
scrollViewContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewContentView];
self.scrollViewContentView = scrollViewContentView;

UILabel *scrollViewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.scrollViewContentView.bounds, 10, 0)];
self.scrollViewLabel = scrollViewLabel;
[self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:scrollViewLabel];
```

- I have implemented this code with my app got such result. You can add number of button in swipe cell.

  Here is implemented screen shots

  [image]After swipe the cell 3 buttons appears "More","Share","Delete".

Answer (score 8):

**This has support for both title and image.**

For iOS 11 and afterwards:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let action = UIContextualAction(
        style: .normal,
        title: "My Title",
        handler: { (action, view, completion) in
            //do what you want here
            completion(true)
    })

    action.image = UIImage(named: "My Image")
    action.backgroundColor = .red
    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return configuration
}
```

Also, similar method is available for `leadingSwipeActions`

*Source:*

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/201/ (Talks about this at around 16 mins time)
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/ (Talks about this at around 23 mins time)

Comment: what about from iOS 9 and above ?

Comment: @MajidBashir My apps do not support the older iOS versions. Sorry, unable to help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use only text while making swipe actions then you can use iOS default swipe actions but if you want image and text, then you have to customize it. I have found a great tutorial and sample that can resolve this problem.

Try out this repository to get the custom swipe cell. You can add multiple option here.

http://iosbucket.blogspot.in/2016/04/custom-swipe-table-view-cell_16.html

https://github.com/pradeep7may/PKSwipeTableViewCell

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        // action one
        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            print("Edit tapped")

            self.myArray.add(indexPath.row)
        })
        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        // action two
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
            print("Delete tapped")

            self.myArray.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

        })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        // action three
        let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Share", handler: { (action , indexPath)in
             print("Share Tapped")
        })
        shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor .green
        return [editAction, deleteAction, shareAction]
    }
```

Comment: would be nice if you added some explanation in the answer itself buddy.

Comment: It would, but I believe the code speaks for itself in this case (considering comments are included and function names are pretty self explainitory)

Answer (score 2):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in
    // share item at indexPath
    }

    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [delete, share]
}
```

The above code shows how to create to custom buttons when your swipe on the row.

Comment: but the swipe is NOT having any effect !! in swift3
Any other methods needed ?

Comment: `tableView(_, commit:, forRowAt:) { }` as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

As I think, It's not best way to using UIGestureRecognizer-based cells.

First, you'll not have any options to use CoreGraphics.

Perfect solution, will [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html) or one `UIGestureRecognizer` for whole table view. Not for every `UITableViewCell`. It will make you app stuck.

Answer (score 0):

create a view on the custom cell in the table view and apply PanGestureRecognizer to the view on the cell.Add the buttons to the custom cell, when you swipe the view on the custom cell then the buttons on the custom cell will be visible.

```
 UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [YourView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And handle the panning on the view in the method

```
 if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    // if the gesture has just started, record the current centre location
    _originalCenter = vwCell.center;
}

// 2
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    // translate the center
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    vwCell.center = CGPointMake(_originalCenter.x + translation.x, _originalCenter.y);
    // determine whether the item has been dragged far enough to initiate  / complete
    _OnDragRelease = vwCell.frame.origin.x < -vwCell.frame.size.width / 2;

}

// 3
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    // the frame this cell would have had before being dragged
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];

    if (_originalCenter.x+translation.x<22) {
          vwCell.center = CGPointMake(22, _originalCenter.y);
        IsvwRelease=YES;

    }
    CGRect originalFrame = CGRectMake(0, vwCell.frame.origin.y,
                                      vwCell.bounds.size.width, vwCell.bounds.size.height);
    if (!_deleteOnDragRelease) {
        // if the item is not being dragged far enough , snap back to the original location
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             vwCell.frame = originalFrame;
                         }
         ];
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have example

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIContextualAction *delete = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal title:nil handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
        
        // your code...
        
    }];
    delete.image  = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"trash"];
    
    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *actions = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:delete, nil]];
    
    return actions;
}
```

Comment: How to trigger `delete` automatically once I swipe to the right???

Comment: You should use - (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. For UIContextualAction action please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560602/add-delete-uitableviewcell-with-animation

Comment: That's what your example is already. And your reference has nothing related to my question: How to trigger `delete` action at the end of the swipe process (without clicking on a button)

Comment: I understand. Please look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration/2902361-performsfirstactionwithfullswipe?language=objc

Comment: I'll rephrase. How to trigger `delete` or any action like WhatsApp `swipe to reply to message` by swiping just 1/3 of the screen and trigger action?

Comment: Sorry, but I can’t understand what do you mean. Please ask the question with attachment which will show your issue and paste here the link.

Answer (score 0):

You shold use [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) for custom swipe cell.