# how to hide default delete button tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I make custom delete button for my `TableViewCell` with this method :

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
    {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([subview class]));
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"])
            {
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [button addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(aMethod:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [button setTitle:@"remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
                button.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 85.0, 60.0);

                [[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:button];


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have one problem. I want my custom button (top button) put instead default delete button.
Now when I swipe my cell show two delete button (first default button & second my custom button) how to hide default delete button???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left. Dude check the link.I hope this is what u want to look

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I swipe my cell show two delete button (first default button
>   & second my custom button) how to hide default delete button???

Override to support conditional editing of the table view cell.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: my friend when I do this code my cell not moving. how to moving and Appearance my custom button???

Comment: What you need exactly? Is that you need to edit the cell(swipe) - your custom delete btw instead of default delete btw??

Comment: my friend I want edit the cell (swipe) another meaning : I want when swipe to left on my cell show my custom button delete for delete my cell!!!

Comment: Instead of adding your own delete btn, try this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615469/custom-delete-button-on-editing-in-uitableview-cell**

Comment: my friend I want make custom button with custom font this post no good for me please guide me more.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and return `NO` inside the delegate method.