# Adding custom edit and delete button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which contains the names of all countries.
The user can delete or edit the name of country anytime by taping on the `cell`.

My UITableView cell initially looks like this:

[image]

Now when user taps on it I am changing it like this:

[image]

I think I am following a very lame approach.Here is what I did:

Declared globally buttons to add:

```
 UIButton *btnDeleteWithImage,*btnDeleteWithText,*btnEditWithImage,*btnEditWihtText; //buttons
```

And a `NSMutableArray` to keep track of `indexPath.row`

Now in my didSelectMethod I am doing this:

```
 //To change the background 
 UIView *selectionBackground = [[UIView alloc] init];

  selectionBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor customColor];

 cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionBackground;

 // to check which cell is pressed

if([indexPathCollection containsObject:index])
{
    [btnDeleteWithImage removeFromSuperview];
    [btnDeleteWithText removeFromSuperview];
    [btnEditWihtText removeFromSuperview];
    [btnEditWithImage removeFromSuperview];
    [indexPathCollection removeObject:index];

    [cell addSubview:btnDeleteWithImage];
    [cell addSubview:btnDeleteWithText];
    [cell addSubview:btnEditWithImage];
    [cell addSubview:btnEditWihtText];
    [indexPathCollection addObject:index];
}
else
{

    [cell addSubview:btnDeleteWithImage];
    [cell addSubview:btnDeleteWithText];
    [cell addSubview:btnEditWithImage];
    [cell addSubview:btnEditWihtText];
    [indexPathCollection addObject:index];
}
```

But this is not working good.When I scroll table edit and delete button randomly occurs.

Did someone has better Idea how can achieve this in a very efficient way.

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left.

Comment: Your approach is not working because you're probably reusing cell in your cellforrowatindexpath delegate method.

Comment: how can I do this... @elbuild please assist me

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a custom cell with your properties

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnDeleteWithImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnDeleteWithText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnEditWithImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btnEditWithText;

@end
```

initialize them in cell's init method keeping them hidden at first or you can do

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"customCellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
        // or you can initialize and add them to the cell here
    }
    //here you can modify them accordingly
    return cell;
}
```

then the delegate method can be

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.btnDeleteWithImage setHidden:NO];
    [cell.btnEditWithImage setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is that do not reuse the cell .  & register your  custom cell with same indentifire .

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

customCell* cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"indentifire"] ;                                      

// manage your plooting here ..

return cell;
}
```

hope it works for you.