# Is there any way to change "DELETE" button from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want to change DELETE button in UITableViewCell. 
Actually, I need to :

1. Change position of button
2. font
3. text color of that button.

Here I can only change button text in following delegate method :

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    UITableViewRowAction *viewAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Follow" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {  

        NSLog(@"View Action fired");  
    }];  
    viewAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

    return @[callAction];  
}
```

But how to change other attributes of button. If anyone knows, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: what other attributes?

Comment: Using standard `UITableViewRowAction` you can't.

Comment: Thanks... @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working, implement the following two methods on your UITableView's delegate to get the desired effect

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// you need to implement this method too esle nothing will work:

}
```

check your method you created the name of **UITableViewRowAction *viewAction** but you returned teh value of **callAction** modify once and try

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
    UITableViewRowAction *callAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Follow" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {  

        NSLog(@"View Action fired");  
    }];  
    callAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

    return @[callAction];  
}
```

In Standard `UITableViewRowAction` we can't change , we can change only

**style**

**title**

**backgroundColor**

**backgroundEffect**

for more information see the [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014688-CH1-SW4)

Comment: I know about which methods I have to implement to get this working...I think you didn't understand my question... :(

Comment: I need solution for changing button properties, not for how to work and what should be implemented..... Anyway thanks for reply... :)

Comment: @VRAwesome - no We Can't, may be alternate way see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left-objective-c-or-swift

Comment: Thanks... @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @VRAwesome  - if you are interested in third party then go by payal answer, may be it solve your issue

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom cell and add custom UIButton into cell. I have a example

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ViewOrderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ViewOrderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.btnUpdate addTarget:self action:@selector(updateOrder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteOrder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)updateOrder:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"update");
}
-(void)deleteOrder:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"delete");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check this - https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views