# Change default delete icons in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How would I change the color of those red .delete markers? Or can I even use custom icons?

[image]

I do *not* want to change the color of these:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change "DELETE" button from UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204100/is-there-any-way-to-change-delete-button-from-uitableviewcell)

Comment: No, this answers how to change the color of the actions that are commonly used as confirmations. I will update my question.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change this red minus view. Reading a little the documentation, I couldn't find a way to have direct access to the views used on each `EditingStyle` enum cases like we have on the confirmation button (the ones you don't want to change), on top of that is deprecated.