# Cannot delete more than some rows in TableView

Tags: ios, tableview

I can delete some rows, but at some point, I cannot delete anymore. The first numbers of rows that I can delete is aleatory.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        [detailProductArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [detailTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Some of you have an idea ?

Comment: Do not call `reloadData` to remove one row.

Comment: @ NRiTH : Yep, completely. 
@rmaddy : If I remove reloadData, it doesn't delete it (at least, in appearance...)

Comment: You have to replace `reloadData` with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: Perfect thanks rmaddy 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to direct you here for a complete answer for removing and adding rows. [Add/Delete UITableViewCell with animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560602/add-delete-uitableviewcell-with-animation)

UITableviewView's can have rows added and removed in an animated fashion using the following methods.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very instructive.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question. @Claudio - can you explain how this answer solved your question?

Comment: [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
This is like your previous comment deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: and the insertIndexPaths: is completing the answer for eventually inserting rows.

Answer (score 0):

My final code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        [detailProductArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [DetailTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }
}
```