# TableView cells don't move down smoothly when removing a cell and using AutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In `UITableView` I can scroll down to see more of the bottom cells. And of course the top most cells get out of the screen. Then I remove a cell with `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)`. The remaining cells move smoothly to fill the gap of a deleted cell. This works until I add automatic dimensions for row height.

But when I set automatic dimensions for row height and delete the bottom cell the remaining cells slide down instantly to fill the gap. Without animation. I guess it's related to setting automatic dimensions, as without it the cells move smoothly.

How to make the cells slide down smoothly even when I use automatic dimension?

In `viewDidLoad()` I set up automatic row dimension with these lines:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

And this is how I remove a cell:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Hi, have you try something like this or with other animation? options:tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)
tableView.endUpdates

Comment: Yes, actually I call `tableView.beginUpdates()` before the line for deleting the row and I call `tableView.endUpdates()` after that line. I'm updating my question to make it clear.

Comment: Why are you removing the cells manually? That's done automatically when scrolling. You only have to take care of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` that's called when recreating the cell.

Comment: @AlejandroIván I use the table view to display data and when the user taps on a specific cell I add a new editing cell to edit data from previous cell. When editing finishes I remove the cell. Adding cells works smooth as it should be. But removing a cell can cause an instant shift down as I've described in my question.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Are you using `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`? Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560602/add-delete-uitableviewcell-with-animation

Comment: I would say the best approach would be to show a new view on top of the table view, calculated with the frame of the cell, instead of messing with the table cells. But that's primarily opinion-based.